# How to avoid using <dynamic_cast> in if statements?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am doing an assignment based around inheritance where I have a social network with 4 classes:

1. a User class with the user's information (id, name, birth year, etc.)
2. a Network class which connects all the users using an adjacency list (a vector of user pointers and each user has a friends list)
3. a Post class that contains the id, message, and the number of likes a post has, and finally,
4. an IncomingPost class that is a child of the Post class but with an additional boolean IsPublic variable to determine whether or not the post is private or public.

The main problem I am having is with the displayPosts function from the User class. The function is supposed to return a string that shows the recent how many posts, and only put the public posts if the showOnlyPublic boolean is true.

I was told to treat Posts as public. I am pretty sure that the rest of my function works, I am just confused about how to check if the Post is public or private, as only the IncomingPost class has an IsPublic boolean, so I can't do messages_[i]->getIsPublic() (I get the error that the Post class doesn't have a function defined as getIsPublic).
How do I make this work for both IncomingPosts and Posts?

Some notes:

- I am not allowed to use <dynamic_cast>
- I will be adding the functionality where the function stops when the messagecount == howmany at a later time

This is my function at the moment:

```
    // post: returns a string shows the most recent howmany posts
    std::string User::displayPosts(std::size_t howmany, bool showOnlyPublic) {
        std::string out;
        std::size_t messagecount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < messages_.size(); i++) {
            if (showOnlyPublic) {
// ************************* PART IN QUESTION IS BELOW ******************************
                // how to only get isPublic if its an IncomingPost?
                // if the post is private 
                if (){ // what to put in here?
                    if (messages_[i]->getIsPublic() == false) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                messagecount++;
                out = out + (messages_[i]->displayPost()) + "\n\n";
            }
            else {
                out = out + (messages_[i]->displayPost()) + "\n\n";
                messagecount++;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Ensure that the base class (`Post`?) (or whatever type `messages_` is) has a `virtual bool getIsPublic()` function. You could also just call `displayPost` regardless, but have your `IncomingPost` class override `displayPost` and ensure it's only displayed if `getIsPublic` is true

Comment: Do you know what virtual functions are, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: I think all you need is explained in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual). Either add interface `bool Post::isPublic()` or add argument to `void Post::displayPost(bool publicOnly = false)` or change the interface to `void Post::displayPrivate` and `void Post::displayPublic`. Dunno, up to you.

Comment: *"I have a social network with 4 classes"* Showing (minimal) code, instead of describing it.